# How i can show my oracle table with knockout.js

Tags: c#, oracle, knockout.js

So this is my table:

```
create table CARS
(
  id           NUMBER not null,
  gender       NUMBER,
  firstname    VARCHAR2(25),
  lastname     VARCHAR2(25),
  manufacturer NUMBER,
  model        NUMBER,
  engine       NUMBER
)
```

and my HTML:

```
            <tr>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>firstName</th>
                <th>lastName</th>
                <th>ManuFacturer</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Engine</th>
            </tr>

        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </table>
```

The thing is im new with knockout.js and with programming also, i've tried to do  "data-bind="text: Gender" but i dont know how if its the correct  way to show my table from the database. I've searched alot, but couldnt find any solutions.. hope some1 can help me..

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language and does not have tables (in the way you mean). You are talking about tables in Oracle SQL.

Comment: Google for "Oracle Apex knockout".

Answer (score 0):

- Knockout.js is a library that is run in the client's web browser.
- Oracle is a database.

In general, it is not possible (or desirable) to connect from any application running in the client's browser directly to any database. There is usually a middle-tier application (i.e PHP, Java, C#, Python/Django, etc.) that sits between the two and manages a pool of connections to the database and the performs queries in response to requests from the client (and handles other things such as user authentication and data formatting).

You need to implement the middle tier and then get your client application to talk to that (and not directly to the database).